# Применение decode в select x from decode

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Дело в том, что есть 2 таблицы, имеющие в себе столбец ID.

Мне необходимо, в случае, если некое_выражение = 0, брать ID из первой таблицы, в противном случае - из второй. Написал селект подобного рода:

```
select ID
from 
decode((ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ), 0, таблица_1, таблица_2)
```

Однако при попытке выполнения возникает ошибка "неверное завершение SQL-предложения". Есть такие-либо варианты реализации необходимого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементарно же:

```
select decode(nekoe_vyrazhenie, 0, t1.id, t2.id)
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on ...
```

`DECODE` - это просто функция такая, ее надо использовать в `SELECT`, а не в `FROM`.

P. S.

> Не нашел подробной информации по подобному вопросу.

Даже в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions057.htm#SQLRF00631) не нашел?

Comment: я знаю как работает decode, не знал, как его адаптировать именно под мою нужду.
После доработки возвращает то, что нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно и без `DECODE`, всё зависит, как выглядит конечный запрос. Можно так:

```
select 
    case :result when '0' then 
         (select id from table1)
    else (select id from table2) end
from dual
;
```

Или ещё так:

```
select id from table1 where :result=0
union all
select id from table1 where :result!=0
;
```